# jQgrid inline edit replacing enter key save with onchange

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jQgrid with two columns, a Name column and a Score column. Only the Score column is editable. Users select a score from a dropdown. They press their Enter key and the score saves. However, the users don't want to press enter. They want the score to save when they select the score in the dropdown (basically, an onchange event).

The Score code looks like this:

```
{name:'RatersScore', index:'RatersScore', width:200, align:'center', sortable:true, search:false, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: "6.0:6.0;6.5:6.5;7.0:7.0;7.5:7.5;8.0:8.0;8.5:8.5;9.0:9.0;9.5:9.5;10.0:10.0", dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: function(e) {myfunction(); } },]}},
```

However nothing happens when the user selects a score from the dropdown. The change is not firing the myfunction().

Users are using IE 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a closer look at their [Documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) you could find the Method (saveRow) that is used for this purpose,

```
{ name: 'Decision', width: 200, editable: true, formatter: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                        value: {
                            '1': 'First Option',
                            '2': 'Second Option',
                            '3': 'third Option'
                        },
                        dataEvents: [
                                {
                                    type: 'change',
                                    fn: function (e) {
                                        var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                        var rowId = row.attr('id');
                                        jQuery("#jQGridId").saveRow(rowId, false, 'clientArray');
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                    }
                    },
```

The function inside the DataEvent fires for every dropdown on change event, 
Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is an elegant solution, but this is what worked for me.

```
{name:'RatersScore', index:'RatersScore', width:200, align:'center', sortable:true, search:false, editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: "6.0:6.0;6.5:6.5;7.0:7.0;7.5:7.5;8.0:8.0;8.5:8.5;9.0:9.0;9.5:9.5;10.0:10.0", dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: function(e) {
var thescore = $(e.target).val();
var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
var thisid= row.attr('id');
var f = $("#frmscores");
var action = '/myController/MyAction?thescore='+thescore+'&theraterid='+thisid;
var serializedForm = f.serialize();
$.post(action, serializedForm,checkscoreResponse,"json");
$('#mygrid').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
} },]}},
```

The serialize is not necessary in this case but I left it there anyway. I'm guessing there is a better way than using the AJAX-like code I have here. There must be a JQuery function that would be better.